# In Objective-C++, Passing structures as function arguments between C++ and ObjC

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, objective-c++

I thought I can pass a C structure from C++ side to ObjC, like this

```
- (voic)myFuncObjc:(aStruct*) mystruct
{
}
```

It turned out that `mystruct` is still unassigned when it gets into the ObjC function even when it's been assigned from C++ side.

And I simply can't pass ObjC structures directly through a C++ function like this

```
void myFuncCpp(anObjCStruct* mystruct)
{
}
```

Are there any idioms to achieve what I want?

Comment: That signature looks incorrect.. try: `-(void) myFuncObjC:(aStruct**) myStruct;`  and in C++:  `extern "C" void myFuncCpp(anObjCStruct** myStruct) {*myStruct = malloc(sizeof(aStruct));}`  You're assigning to a local pointer or a copy of a pointer (aka the parameter).. you need a pointer to a pointer OR a reference to a pointer.

Comment: how do you call it? if `aStruct` is small, you can pass it by value

Comment: @Brandon Thank you! Been using references for so long and forgot the pointer argument nuance. From your second example, does it mean that when passing an ObjC to C++ side, even though the ObjC object is already allocated, I'd need to freshly allocate it?

Comment: If it's already allocated then just pass the pointer like you already have in your original signature (not the one I gave you). Obj-C to C++ = your signature. C++ to Obj-C is the one I gave you ONLY if you plan to allocate on the C++ side. Obj-C to C++ or C++ to Obj-C is your signature if you plan on "copying" via `memcpy`. I can post an example if you like.

Comment: I'd much appreciate it if you could copy your comments as an answer and kindly add an example. I'll accept it as the correct answer when the system opens the slot. Thank you very much!